# Javascript refusing to work?

Tags: javascript, html, firebug

Well I am coding a little game with js using a HTML5 canvas. I got the canvas and the  tag in a html file and the javascript in a seperate file called java.js.

I got some alerts at some moment in the script to find out if it runs when I load the html into my browser. Problem is it does not show any of these and the javascript doesnt load.

The weirdest is what firebug does: Under "HTML" it shows me the full script when I click the  tag, but under "Script" it tells me there is no javascript on the page.

Help?

my html:

```
    <body><canvas id="canvas" width="1000px" height="500px" style="border:1px solid #c3c3c3;">text</canvas>
<script type="text/javascript" src="java.js">
</script></body>
```

When I put the script tag in the head:

```
<head><script type="text/javascript" src="java.js">
    </script></head> 
<body><canvas id="canvas" width="1000px" height="500px" style="border:1px solid #c3c3c3;">text</canvas>
    </body>
```

my js:

```
alert('define');
var scrollx=0,
scrolly=0,
keyID=0,
global = {};
global.players=[];
global.playermap=[];
var c=document.getElementById("canvas"),
ctx=c.getContext('2d');
alert('init');

function pony (x,y, hspd, vspd) {
alert("pony created!");
this.x = x;
this.y = y;
this.vsp = vspd;
this.hspd = hspd;
this.image = new Image();
this.image.src = "alien.png";
this.framenumber = 11;
this.frameactual = 1;
this.framespeed=0.8;
this.frametime =50;
this.framewidth = this.image.width / this.framenumber;
this.frameheight = this.image.height;
this.colorbody="#000000";
//
this.nextframe = function() {
this.frameactual=this.frameactual+this.framespeed;
if (Math.round(this.frameactual)>this.framenumber){this.frameactual=1;}
this.draw();
};
//
this.draw = function() {
this.frame=Math.round(this.frameactual);
ctx.drawImage(this.image,(this.frame-1)*this.framewidth,0,this.framewidth,this.image.height,this.x-scrollx-(this.framewidth/2),this.y-scrolly-(this.image.height/2),this.framewidth,this.image.height);
};
//
//var _this=this;
//this.frametimer=setInterval(function(){_this.nextframe();},this.frametime);
alert("time set");
}
//
function setpos_player(id,x,y,hspd,vspd){
alert("this");
if (typeof(global.playermap[id])=="undefined"){
global.players.push(new pony (x,y, hspd, vspd));
global.playermap[id]=global.players.length;}
else{
global.players[global.playermap[id]].x=x;
global.players[global.playermap[id]].y=y;
global.players[global.playermap[id]].hspd=hspd;
global.players[global.playermap[id]].vspd=vspd;}
}
//
function clear(){
    ctx.fillStyle = "#FFFFFF";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(0,0,1000,1000);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();}

document.onkeypress = KeyCheck; 
document.onkeydown = KeyCheck;     
document.onkeyup = KeyRelease;   

function KeyCheck(e)

{
   keyID = (window.event) ? event.keyCode : e.keyCode;
   }
function KeyRelease(e)
{keyID=0;}

//
function step(){
clear();
for (var i = 0; i < global.players.length; i++) {
    _this=global.players[i];
    _this.y+=_this.vspd;
    _this.nextframe();
    //Do something
}
//global.players[1].nextframe();
timer=setTimeout(function(){step();},80);
}
setpos_player(1,200,200,0,1);
var timer=setTimeout(function(){step();},80);
```

Comment: Just a sidenote. `java.js` does not make any sense. `javascript` is not `java`.

Comment: So which is it? Pony or alien?

Comment: You have not accepted any answers! Kindly improve that if you want a better response.

Comment: Optimus: It's just a random name, I know javascript isn't java.
Chaos: alien.png is the pic I am using for testing, and pony is the object name
Ashwin: What do you mean by haven't accepted? I tried all of them and replied using comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems you have an error here:

```
if (typeof(global.playermap[id])="undefined"){
```

should be

```
if (typeof(global.playermap[id])=="undefined"){
```

also, try replacing all `alert` calls to `console.log` and then check out the console for errs

Comment: Do you know that JS uses translator, and actually the error will be displayed when it comes to this lane. The problem described is that no js file is loaded -> no allert is shown.

Comment: Strangely it works now, such a small thing can cause so much trouble. XD

Answer (score 0):

declare script before you use it in the html
you can put that script in head of the page like this

```
<head>
<script type='text/javascript' src='java.js'></script>
</head>
```

try it once and replay here

Answer (score 0):

```
if (typeof(global.playermap[id])="undefined"){
```

to

```
if (typeof global.playermap[id] == "undefined"){
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to put the right directory path for the .js file. For example it may be /java.js or "/scripts/java.js".

The indication if javascript is loaded will be if your alert pops up.

Also, you should know that script tags, with external .js should be added in HEAD section.

Comment: I saw alot of applications that worked just fine when the javascript was loaded in body, but meh I'll try loading it in the head.

Comment: external JS files should be loaded at the BOTTOM of the document...just before the closing body tag.

Comment: I never said it will not work. Not closing the html tag will also work, but it is just not correct. Scripts are declared in the body ONLY if you want specific logic to be executed there. However using function call is much more efficient and looks much better.

Comment: @Bonny Bonev you want your JS links to be at the bottom of your page--NOT in the head: http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#js_bottom